# Replace values in a pandas series from list of tuples

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization, series

Problem: Want to replace values in a pandas series from a value in the list of tuples where a particular series value should start with the first value of the tuple. Below is an example:

```
a = pd.Series(['New Delhi', 'Old Bombay', None, 'Banaras'])

b = [('New','Old'), ('Old','New'),('Banaras','Varanasi'), ('abc','xyz')]

Required Output :
0         Old
1         New
2        None
3    Varanasi
dtype: object
```

I tried below and it works like a charm, however as apply loses the benefit of vectorization, hence it is slow.

```
def test(x):
    if x is not None:
        for i in b:
            if x.startswith(i[0]):
                return i[1]
        return x
    return x


a.apply(test)

I tried list comprehension that also works but is still slow. 

pd.Series([test(x) for x in a])
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this without losing the benefit of vectorization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is faster, but it's an alternative:

```
a.str.partition(' ').iloc[:,0].replace(*zip(*b))
```

Result:

```
0         Old
1         New
2        None
3    Varanasi
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

**Update for starting values containing spaces**:

```
to_replace,value = zip(*b)
to_replace = [f'^{x}.*$' for x in to_replace]
a.replace(to_replace, value, regex=True)
```

Example:

```
a = pd.Series(['New Delhi', 'Old Bombay', None, 'Banaras', 'Greater city'])
b = [('New','Old'), ('Old','New'),('Banaras','Varanasi'), ('abc','xyz'), ('Greater city', 'Great' )]
```

Result:

```
0         Old
1         New
2        None
3    Varanasi
4       Great
dtype: object
```

Comment: What will happen if the data has something like in the b =[ ('Greater city', 'Great' ) ]

Comment: This will never be applied as the to_replace value can't contain spaces. Please see my updated answer for this case.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of struggle and research on the internet, got to know that np.select is the better way to go and is vectorized. Below is the solution which outperforms in case when the Series (a) is big enough. Below is the solution:

```
a = pd.Series(np.random.choice(['New Delhi', 'Old Bombay', None, 'Banaras'], replace=True, size=1000000))

case = [a.str.upper().str.startswith(i[0], na=False) for i in b]

replace = [i[1] for i in b]

%timeit -n10 -r10 pd.Series(np.select(case, replace, default=a))
10 loops, best of 10: 75.3 ms per loop
```